# Java и Python

Tags: python, java

Почему Python с Java считают языками разного уровня?

Comment: Покажите, где так считают

Comment: Поясните, что означает "разного уровня"?

Comment: Уже не могу найти, где я это прочитал.
Но, к примеру, на Java написана Apache cassandra, а на python ниечего подобного не делают.

Comment: В этом случае вопрос в производительности. Java на порядок быстрее, чем Python, в среднем. Так же, как и хорошо оптимизированный C/C++ в несколько раз быстрее, чем Java. С уровнем абстракции от железа коррелирует, но в прямой зависимости не находится.

Comment: @Egor2010, Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спросите у того, кто это сказал, что он понимает под "уровнями".

Часто под уровнем понимают то, насколько язык далёк от машинного языка. Ассемблер в таком случае — низкоуровневый; Си — выше; языки с более богатыми абстракциями, которые не имеют очевидного представления на уровне машины (объектно-ориентированные, функциональные) — ещё выше; языки, в которых формулируется задача, но не процесс её решения — ещё выше. С этой точки зрения Джава и Питон находятся на примерно одном уровне: это высокоуровневые мультипарадигменные языки общего назначения. Из ключевых отличий у них различается типизация (строгая против утиной), но на *уровень* это никак не влияет. Впрочем, при большом желании утиную типизацию можно считать более "высокоуровневой", так как для машины она сложнее.

Comment: Причем если речь не шла об уровне типа "ява для крутых чуваков а питон для лошков", то говорить о уровне этих языков вообще нет смысла, так как сравнить можно лишь реализации интерпретаторов. Реализации самого языка есть и под ту же JVM и под llvm.

Comment: @LinnTroll По системе "для крутых / для лохов" странно было бы останавливаться на Java. В среднем по больнице хардкорный C++ и уж тем более ASM более "круты". Впрочем, зависит от того, перед кем выделываешься...

Comment: Ну это по классификации: ява - это кровавый интерпрайз для мужиков в костюмах, а питон - наколенные скрипты для пацанов в шортах)

Comment: Asm крут? Эээ... Я думал, на нём серьёзно пишут лишь на платформах, под которые нет адекватного оптимизирующего компилятора. Представьте себе, какая квалификация нужна, чтобы написать на ассмеблере аналог

    File.ReadLines("numbers.txt").Select(l => l.Split().Sum(int.Parse)).Max();

? И насколько такой код будет компактен и поддерживаем.

Comment: @VladD На ассемблере скорее оптимизируют узкие места, когда нужно выжать всё возможное из железа. И вот для того, чтобы оптимизировать лучше сишного компилятора, таки надо быть весьма и весьма крутым. Чтобы писать код вроде вашего — да, и на асме много ума не надо; да, смысла в этом ноль.

К слову, код у вас офигительно неоптимальный: один символ обрабатывается три раза (ReadLines, Split, Parse), создаётся тьма тьмущая мусора в памяти (Split в основном), без дела дёргаются локали (медленно и обычно не нужно). Если критичны скорость и память, вы даже на C# написали бы совсем по-другому.

Comment: @Athari: 1) По времени неважно: время пробега доминируется чтением из файловой системы. 2) Мусор в памяти? И что? Задача минимального по потреблению памяти алгоритма нужна очень редко, и точно не в этой предметной области. Тем более, что большая часть кода lazy. Тем более, что аллокация памяти в .NET дешёвая, этом вам не `malloc`. 3) Локали как раз нужны, иначе с какими-нибудь индийскими цифрами код не сработает. Мир ведь не заканчивается Европой?

Comment: 1. Ось может закинуть (и закинет) весь файл в оперативную память, если позволяют ресурсы. Чтения файла с диска при повторном запуске может вообще не быть.
2. Вы не задали предметную область. Скажем, при написании игр на C# или Java мусор в памяти — это очень и очень критично. Ну и Split [отвратительно засирает память и запросто вылетает в LOH](https://ajdotnet.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/the-cost-of-string-split/).
3. Что у вас за текстовый файлик с индийскими цифрами-то? Скажем, если в конфигурационном файле парсинг чисел зависит от локали, то это неверно. Без условий задачи нет критериев.

Comment: @Athari: 1) Даже если так, гарантированная производительность всё равно зависит от диска. А если диск ещё и сетевой... 2) Ну да, это ж пример на пальцах. Для игр AI и бизнес-логика вполне могут себе быть написанными без строгой оглядки на память, т. к. объёмы потребляемой памяти исчисляются несчастными десятками-сотнями килобайт. А графический движок, да, критичен к памяти. Но его и лучше писать на нативных языках.

Comment: @Athari: 3) Нормальный себе файлик. Вот более жизненный для нас пример — десятичный разделитель. Конфигурационный файл, понятно, должен быть в фиксированной локали, а вот файлы, приходящие из внешних источников, обычно в местной локали. А теперь прикиньте поддержку этой самой локали на ассемблере. Разве что ОС поможет. Кстати, по поводу локали и прочего: http://blog.codinghorror.com/on-managed-code-performance-again/

Comment: 1. Таки в вашем примере диск не сетевой (нормальные люди из шары приложения не запускают).
2. Вы спорите с общеизвестными фактами. Игра — это не гуёвое приложение, в котором достаточно простоев для сборки мусора. Если у вас в алгоритме 50 MB выделяется один раз — это чихать. А если это происходит на 60 FPS, то это поток 3 GB/s. И юзер каждую сборку будет прекрасно видеть, потому что кадры будут пропускаться.
3. На ассемблере поддержка локали будет делегирована оси или сторонней библиотеке (абсолютно как и в .NET, замечу — там никакой магии).

Comment: @VladD Цикл статей прикольный, но меня напрягло, что ни один из разрабов не почесался выяснить, откуда выползла синхронизация в однопоточном приложении (где `std::ios::sync_with_stdio`?!). Зачем-то оба выделяли отдельные строки (хранить достаточно индексы, выделять по необходимости, когда надо отобразить; это же решило бы проседание версии на .NET по памяти). Реймонд так и не переписал парсинг на автомат (а это нехилый прирост в скорости).
Ну и делать выводы на этом сравнении невозможно. Сравните хотя бы, как поживают библиотеки для математических рассчётов.

Comment: @Athari: 1) Мы же говорит не о приложении, а о данных, правильно? (И да, почему нормальные люди не запускают приложения из сетевого диска? Допустим, у меня Linux box, и home лежит на сетевом диске — вполне типичная конфигурация.)

2) Тут спора нет. Мой тезис — _подавляющей_ части кода выжимание последнего байта не нужно. А значит, и не нужен ассемблер.

3) Не-не, не сруливайте :-) Пишем на ассемблере — значит, руками, только руками, вдруг внешний алгоритм написан неэффективно?

Comment: @Athari: `std::ios::sync_with_stdio` выползло из необходимости стандартной библиотеки поддерживать консистентность вывода через `cout` и `printf`. Хранить индексы в исходном файле не получится, т. к. строки надо перекодировать в Unicode. А выгоды от автомата не вижу: он и так каждый байт проходит один раз. Наоборот, построчный парсинг даёт возможность конвертировать строку в один присест, а не посимвольно ([выигрыш в производительности](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/16/417865.aspx)).

Comment: @Athari: Суть этого цикла статей (для меня) такова: там, где нужно что-то нетривиальное (а матбиблиотеки с т. зр. языка — примитив), высокоуровневый код показывает искаропки хорошую производительность. Тогда «зачем платить больше»? (ц)

Comment: @Athari: (Проблема не в комментировании закрытых вопросов, а в лимите в 4 комментария на человека. Но на сервере этот лимит не проверяется, ЕВПОЧЯ. Если вы удалите верхние комментарии, возможность комментировать вернётся.)

Возвращаясь к исходной теме: я не думаю, что знание низкоуровневых трюков, которые практически никогда не нужны, есть какая-либо «крутость». Сложность задач, которые решаются на высокоуровневых языках, обычно на несколько порядков превосходят сложность задач, решаемых на ассемблере.

Comment: @Athari: А по поводу одной аллокации — боюсь, вы торгуете временем старта за время пробега. Если вам надо отображать строку в UI (что есть целью программы), то недостаточно передать пару индексов, т. к. UI framework не знает о том, что именно это и есть строка. Таким образом, вам придётся _много раз_ извлекать подстроку, а это нехорошо.

В любом случае, единственным критерием истины является профилирование. Напишете свой алгоритм?